# What type should I make a function that returns an exit state in C++

Tags: c++, function

I am writing a function that checks whether a file can be opened or not. However, I don't know if bool is the correct type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
bool checkFileOpen (ifstream fin)
{
  if (!fin)
  {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

Comment: That function checks if a file *is open*, not whether it "can be opened".

Comment: If `EXIT_FAILURE` is non-zero this will be returned as `true`. Why not `return false`?

Comment: This function should not return an exit state. It should return `true` or `false`, and leave it up to the caller to decide how to handle failure.

Answer (score 1):

They are intended to be returned from `main` or passed to `exit`, so the proper type is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status, those macros are `/*implementation defined*/`

You can either look it up for your platform, or translate to the type of your chooosing.

Comment: They are intended to be returned from `main` whose return type is `int`